# Best Practices Domain Entities Composition?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I have the following project structure:

```
- Application.DataAccess      : IUserRepository....
- Application.DataAccess      : IUserRepository....
- Application.business        : IUserService, ICustomerService...
- Application.Infrastructure  : Logging, Exception handling... (Cross-cutting.)
- Application.Domain          : User, Customer... (Entities)
- Application.WindowsForms    : UI
```

Almost all of my service operations will have the following parameters:

- `User userOfOperation` (That is in **Doimain** layer and represents a user)
- `PlaceOfOperation placeOfOperation`  (That is in **Doimain** layer and represents a branch office)

I think that i should create a new class and encapsulate this entities on it then call it"OperationSource".

like:

```
class OperationSource 
{
   Domain.User UserOfOperation { get; set; }
   Domain.Enterprise PlaceOfOperation { get; set; }
}
```

Where should i put the compose classes (e.g OperationSource) in this case, on my Application.**Busines** or Application.**Domain**?

Answer (score 0):

You could model your business logic into service classes and place them in a new package "service". The idea is that entities and composites do not implement any business rules but represent just the resource tier. Service classes implement business logic that work across entities and composites. (loosed adapation of DDD-Domain Driven Design).